# Golang returning functions

Tags: go, nested-function

> Can anyone explain why 0's and 1's are printed and not anything else? Thank you!

```
func makeFunction(name string) func() {
    fmt.Println("00000")
    return func() {
        makeFunction2("abcef")
    }
}

func makeFunction2(name string) func() {
    fmt.Println("11111")
    return func() {
        makeFunction3("safsf")
    }
}

func makeFunction3(name string) func() {
    fmt.Println("33333")
    return func() {
        fmt.Printf("444444")
    }
}

func main() {
    f := makeFunction("hellooo")
    f()
}
```

Can anyone explain why 0's and 1's are printed and not anything else? Thank you!

Comment: Because you never call `makeFunction3`, its return value, and never print the `name` values? I'm not sure what you expect.

Comment: If you are going to call a chain of functions, with the same signature, I suggest take a look at implementing a FSM (Finite State Machine) in Go. This is not a full fledged FSM, but provides the essence, which makes these sort of tasks far cleaner. See this part by Rob Pike https://youtu.be/HxaD_trXwRE?t=14m7s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's look at your `main`:

#### Line 1

```
f := makeFunction("hellooo")
```

- Side effect: printing "00000"
- Return value: an anonymous function that executes `makeFunction2("abcef")`, assigned to the identifier `f`

#### Line 2

```
f()
```

which is equivalent to:

```
_ = f()
```

- Side effect: printing "11111"
- Return value: an anonymous function that executes `makeFunction3("safsf")`, discarded (you are not assigning the return value of `f()`).

`makeFunction3` is never assigned to any identifier, and never called.

Answer (score 15):

Let's follow the program flow:

1. `main` starts.
2. `main` calls `makeFunction`.
3. `makeFunction` prints `00000`, and returns an anonymous function.
4. Back in `main`, we call the anonymous function returned by the previous call.
5. The anonymous function calls `makeFunction2`.
6. `makeFunction2` prints `11111`, and returns an anonymous function.
7. `main` returns.

Because the return value is discarded after step 6 above, nothing else is printed.

Answer (score 4):

To prints the 3's, you have to call twice:

```
f()()
```

And to prints the 4's too, just do:

```
f()()()
```

Because ...

```
// prints "00000" and returns a function that if run
// will invoked `makeFunction2`
f := makeFunction("hello")

// `makeFunction2` is called, printing "11111" and returns 
// a function that if run will invoked `makeFunction3`
f1 := f()

// `makeFunction3` is called, printing "33333" and returns
// a function that if run will invoked `makeFunction4`
f2 := f1()
```

Test question, what does it print out if you do this?

```
f := makeFunction("Hello")()()
f()
```

This is known as currying or closure, but in your example you have not closed over any local value so the latter loses its meaning.

Answer (score 0):

makeFunction only return the function makeFunction2. since this is not a recursive function. If you expecting to behave like recursive function, then you should change return func(){} to (return makeFunction2 or 3)

```
func makeFunction(name string) func() {
    fmt.Println("00000")
    return makeFunction2("abcef")
}

func makeFunction2(name string) func() {
    fmt.Println("11111")
    return makeFunction3("safsf")
}

func makeFunction3(name string) func() {
    fmt.Println("33333")
    return func() {
        fmt.Printf("444444")
    }
}

func main() {
    f := makeFunction("hellooo")
    f()
}

// Output: 
00000
11111
33333
444444
```

Answer (score 0):

The Reason is it only returns the anonymous funtions.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func makeFunction(name string) func() {
    fmt.Println("00000")
    return func(){
        makeFunction2("abcef")()
    }
}

func makeFunction2(name string) func() {
    fmt.Println("11111")
    return func() {
        makeFunction3("safsf")()
    }
}

func makeFunction3(name string) func() {
    fmt.Println("33333")
    return func() {
        fmt.Printf("444444")
    }
}

func main() {
    f := makeFunction("hellooo")
    f()
}
```